# Extend Silverlight Combobox's dropdown over aspx content

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have an aspx page, with a div that I want to replace with a Silverlight application. The content inside this div is responsible for filtering some data, and is quite small (200 pixels x 200 pixels about).

One of the comboboxes in the Silverlight app that I made to replace that content, contains a long list of items.

If I expand that combobox, it only fills the space available to the Silverlight control, i.e. 200x200 pixels. Is it possible to have the combobox dropdown extend to outside the Silverlight control's confines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Silverlight in [windowless mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (in this mode you can put html over silverlight) and use list from HTML which will be over Silverlight.
Silverlight combobox can't extend beyond the Silverlight area.

If the list of items so long, you can simply use scrolling in the combobox.

Comment: "Silverlight combobox can't extend beyond the silverlight area." What I was looking for.